# Как оставаться на текущей / переключиться на предыдущую вкладку?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, chrome-extension, расширения

Недавно изучил написание расширения Chrome.
Сейчас моё расширение работает с манипуляцией страницы некого сайта в интернете. При определенном действии запускается window.open() по ссылке, и соответственно происходит переключение на эту новую страницу - вкладку в браузере.

Но я бы хотел оставаться на текущей странице. Как понял из гугл это невозможно. Тогда решил пойти путём переключения на предыдущую вкладку после открытия новой.

Тут я наткнулся на такую штуку как tabid -  т.е. решил что можно запомнить id вкладки, и переходить на неё. Здесь применяется chrome.tabs.query

Тут тоже обнаружился подвох - этот метод можно вызывать только в background.js

ок, дальше я наткнулся на такие методы как

в background.js:
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener

в script.js (который работает со страницей сайта)
chrome.runtime.sendMessage

и что-то пытался сделать на основе этого. Вроде примеров полно в интернете, но не для моего случая.

У меня не срабатывал sendResponse

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(

  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true},

      function(tabs) {

        var currTab = tabs[0];
        if (currTab) {
        
          console.log(currTab.id);
          sendResponse({tabId: currTab.id}); 

      }

  });


});
```

И вообще не совсем понятно что делать с этим дальше.

Итак - как мне вернуться... Мне всего лишь нужно вернуться на предыдущую вкладку... :)

Может быть на основе тех методов, может быть есть другие ходы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897430/prevent-window-open-from-focusing/6897462#6897462

Однако после этого перестал работать window.close() . Решил это таким кодом в бекграунде (background.js)

```js
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,
    function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.remove(sender.tab.id);
});
```